# getting the value on a list with a combined index

Tags: python, list, integer

```
coded = ['','','','','','','','','','',
        'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',
        'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
        's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ']

def decode(decode):
     out = ''
     for x in range(1, len(str(decode)) // 2):
          out += coded[int(str(decode[x * 2 - 2]) + str(decode[x * 2 - 1]))]  #here is the issue
     return out

print(decode(16133335202320))
```

im trying to get a value from a list with every 2 characters from the input value.
but, where ive commented, it keeps coming up with "int' object is not subscriptable".

how do i fix this?

Comment: `str(decode)[...]` instead of `str(decode[...])`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your number to string before:

```
>>> print(decode(16133335202320))
...
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable


#         HERE ---v
>>> print(decode(str(16133335202320)))
gdxzkn
```

**OR**

You can rewrite your function like below:

```
def decode(decode):
     decode = str(decode)
     out = ''
     for x in range(1, len(decode) // 2):
          out += coded[int(decode[x * 2 - 2] + decode[x * 2 - 1])]
     return out
```

```
>>> print(decode(16133335202320))
gdxzkn
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [fischmalte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12756686/fischmalte)'s comment:

```py
coded = ['','','','','','','','','','',
        'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i',
        'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r',
        's','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ']

def decode(decode):
    out = ''
    for x in range(1, len(str(decode)) // 2):
        out += coded[int(str(decode)[x * 2 - 2] + str(decode)[x * 2 - 1])] ### EDITED LINE
    return out

print(decode(16133335202320))
```

Change `str(decode[x * 2 - 2])` to `str(decode)[x * 2 - 2]` and `str(decode[x * 2 - 1])` to `str(decode)[x * 2 - 1]`.